# ngCordova get GCM regid inside a controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm having troubles trying to register my GCM regid with ngCordova and $cordovaPush.

I can't manage to retrieve my regid inside my controller to send it to my API via $http:

```
var gcmToken;
gcmNotificationHandler = function(e) {
    if (e.event === "registered") {
        gcmToken = e.regid;
        console.log(gcmToken);
    }
};
var aTonAvis = angular.module('aTonAvis', ['ngCordova']);
aTonAvis.value('serverUrl', "http://atonavis.local/");
aTonAvis.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaPush,
    $cordovaDevice, $http, serverUrl) {
    var gcmConfig = {
        "senderID": "00000000000"
    };
    var iosConfig = {
        "badge": "true",
        "sound": "true",
        "alert": "true",
    };
    gcmConfig.ecb = "gcmNotificationHandler";
    iosConfig.ecb = "iosNotificationHandler";
    var configHandler = function() {
        if ($cordovaDevice.getPlatform().toLowerCase() ===
            'android' || $cordovaDevice.getPlatform() ===
            'amazon-fireos') {
            return gcmConfig;
        } else {
            return iosConfig;
        }
    };
    this.registered = false;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady() {
        $cordovaPush.register(configHandler()).then(function(
            result) {
            console.log("Inside register " + gcmToken);
            var pushToken;
            if ($cordovaDevice.getPlatform().toLowerCase() ===
                'ios') pushToken = result;
            else pushToken = gcmToken;
            $http.post(serverUrl + 'api/setdevice', {
                token: pushToken,
                device: $cordovaDevice.getPlatform(),
                version: $cordovaDevice.getVersion(),
                model: $cordovaDevice.getModel()
            }).success(function(data, status,
                headers, config) {
                this.registered = true;
            });
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("Registering Error : " + err);
        });
    });
});
```

The .then function is fired before the gcmNotificationHandler so my gcmToken is undefined, and here's what I get in my logs :

```
Inside register : undefined app.js:41
APA91bEzVUk3T1T6WpIsEHOq43hCh_pZeBPjRDPSPxV2j6VjVW-KcUepbmf6snaCiqGvYp3H_XYHIXQdbVtvMF3t-NtoZJaJzV9FkNtUlutuWYs5XPAZ-H1ixQnAyhTO6fAPDMn7Ef5f5HgBR9fgWpmXc0u_xBM4yKvoXCnVXEG18IZV2hvY app.js:6
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install these two cordova plugins before run the app.

Device cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device
```

Console cordova plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console
```

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/11/14/implement-push-notifications-for-android-and-ios-phonegap-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that uses ngCordova with PushPlugin. The regid comes in the same callback for event 'pushNotificationReceived' for android. Here is the code I use within the callback for that event to receive the regid from GCM:

Checking for (notification.event === 'registered') is the most important.

```
$rootScope.$on('pushNotificationReceived', function(event, notification) {

  //console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(event));
  console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(notification));        

  console.log('Success: Inside the push notification received callback with this payload JSON' + notification);

  if(( platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android' ) && notification.regid && (notification.event === 'registered'))
  {
    var googDevToken = notification.regid;
    console.log(googDevToken);
  }

});
```